# unity: EdgeCollider2D同士の衝突判定がとれない

Tags: unity3d

EdgeCollider2DとCircleCollider2Dとの当たり判定は取得できるのですが、EdgeCollider2D同士は反応しませんでした。仕様でしょうか？よろしくお願いします。

unity 5.2.1

Answer (score 1):

ttp://answers.unity3d.com/questions/832350/no-collision-with-edge-collider-2d.html
Unity2D剛体にはBox2Dライブラリが使用されていて、
UnityEdgeCollider2D同士は衝突しません(体積がないからとのこと)。
PolygonCollider2DでEdgeCollider2Dの代用が可能です。